# systemctl doesn't recognize my service: Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I want to define a simple service to be started at boot, being on Ubuntu server 16.10. So I have created a `/etc/init.d/mydaemon`

I somehow messed up between upstart and systemd: at first I thought I had to setup an upstart service. So after converting my file to an upstart syntax, I ran `update-rc.d mydaemon defaults`.

I figured out my error and ran `update-rc.d mydaemon remove`, converted to systemd syntax, and ran `systemctl enable mydaemon`, but get the error:

```
mydaemon.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mydaemon
update-rc.d: error: mydaemonDefault-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was the location of the file, on Ubuntu server it expects it in `/etc/systemd/system`, `/etc/init.d/` is for legacy files.

Comment: this solution fixed my service

Comment: I think this solution does not work if the init script is a bash script. Instead of copying the file, parameters on the run levels must be added as comments as nick fox posted in their answer.

Comment: Sure, the initial question is on a `.service` file, not a bash init script.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same error when porting a sysv script from a redhat box to ubuntu. I needed to add some headers to the script

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-service-name
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO
```

found in https://askubuntu.com/questions/909523/default-start-contains-no-runlevels-aborting

Comment: see also https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: My script already have this reader but still showing the exactly same error.. =[

Answer (score 9):

Just to add on to the answer from @CharlesB - when I got into this state I was able to simply move the file from `/etc/init.d/` to `/etc/systemd/system/` and rerun the command and it worked properly:

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/mydaemon /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable mydaemon
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I think it's an easier to follow answer, so made it one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I fixed it putting the default start information, as follow:

```
vi /etc/init.d/greenbone-security-assistant
```

Change from:

```
# Default-Start:
```

to:

```
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
```

:wq

root@kali:/etc/init.d# systemctl enable greenbone-security-assistant

Synchronizing state of greenbone-security-assistant.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.

Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable greenbone-security-assistant